# Network plug didnt work

Tags: linux, ethernet, hardware-failure

Suddenly the Ethernet port does not work, the leds isnt flashing, and it is not recognized any wired connection.

I have removed the cover of the laptop but I didnt find anything burned, damaged or unwired.
The pins look al soldered and fine.

The test was done with several cables and two diferent routers in several ports.

What can be done to verify if the port is working or get back to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These connectors are fairly durable but can break.

Try the following:

Use the tools in Linux to see if the Device is active. You can try installing the LAN Driver for Linux.  Use the PC Manufacturer's support site for this.

Get the PC Manufacturer's Hardware Test app that makes a bootable USB Key.  Boot with that and run a complete set of tests. See if the NIC comes up bad.

Try both things to determine if the port has gone bad.